# Why is findFirst() throwing a NullPointerException if I'm priorly filtering only for present() values?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a `Stream` of Strings, and am mapping each String to `Optional<String>`. Since I'm filtering empty `Optionals` afterwards, the returned stream should only contain non-empty `Optionals` holding non-null Strings.

Why is `findFirst()` throwing a `NullPointerException` then?

```
Optional<String> cookie = 
  Stream.of(headers.get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE), headers.get(HttpHeaders.COOKIE))
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(s -> s.contains("identifier"))
                        .map(this::parseCookieValue) //returns an Optional<String> from Optional.ofNullable(), null-values should result in empty Optionals
                        .filter(Optional::isPresent) // filters out non-present values
                        .map(Optional::get) // all Optionals here should have values
                        .findFirst(); // so why is this still throwing a NullPointerException?
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl$$Lambda$11/873175411.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:529)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:516)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl.login(RestServiceImpl.java:81)
```

Line 81 is the `findFirst()`-method call.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example with some dummy data?

Comment: Please provide the whole stacktrace of the exception. I strongly suspect that the real cause of NPE is not the `findFirst` (but probably `s -> s.contains(...)` lambda).

Comment: @TagirValeev that was my first thought too. There is an issue with writing massing one-liners - it is somewhat harder to debug...

Comment: @AlexisC. That was just an oversight in the example snippet, it's corrected, no need to close the whole question because of that. I will post the stacktrace.

Comment: @AlexisC. Sorry I just assumed that. Writing the reproducible example actually led me to the mistake! I'll post an answer.

Comment: As a side note, if you have just two lists, `Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream())` is more concise than `Stream.of(a, b).flatmap(Collection::stream)`

Comment: @TagirValeev I'm a bit surprised about the quick off-topic vote since it's not.. anyway, the stacktrace is also posted.

Comment: @Blacklight, closevotes mean that "this question is not useful for further readers". You should not worry about them as you've solved your problem. Actually things were much simpler if you post stacktrace from the very beginning. Now I cast a reopen vote as I can explain in the answer how to properly read the stacktrace of the exception appeared in Stream API call. But I doubt you will gather enough reopen votes. Just remember for the future: if you ask "why I see such exception", *always* post a stacktrace.

Comment: @TagirValeev Fair enough! I agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading exceptions which appear inside the Stream API is not trivial. First thing you should not forget is that Stream is lazy: everything is actually executed inside the terminal operation. Thus in your case the whole Stream processing is executed inside the `findFirst` call and if you see the `NullPointerException` it can be produced by any step of your pipeline, not just by `findFirst` itself. Let's take a closer look to the top of stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl$$Lambda$11/873175411.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
```

If you have some `Spliterator.tryAdvance` or `Spliterator.forEachRemaining` call in the trace, then the exception actually occurred during the processing of some stream element, not during the final operations. Here's how the exception looks like if you actually pass the null value to the `findFirst`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Optional.<init>(Optional.java:96)
    at java.util.Optional.of(Optional.java:108)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:190)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
```

See, no spliterator calls here: it finished per-element processing and throws after that.

The topmost stackframe in your case reads as `com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl$$Lambda$11/873175411.apply`. The `NullPointerException` inside the autogenerated lambda which does not point to any known code usually means that unbound method reference is called for null `this` argument. To make this more clear you can replace all the method references in your code with lambdas as they actually have a source line:

```
Optional<String> cookie = 
  Stream.of(headers.get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE), headers.get(HttpHeaders.COOKIE))
                        .flatMap(c -> c.stream())
                        .filter(s -> s.contains("identifier"))
                        .map(c -> this.parseCookieValue(c))
                        .filter(opt -> opt.isPresent())
                        .map(opt -> opt.get())
                        .findFirst();
```

Now you will see the additional frame with the line number:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl.lambda$0(RestServiceImpl.java:14)
    at com.example.services.impl.RestServiceImpl$$Lambda$1/2055281021.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
```

This line number points exactly to the `.flatMap(c -> c.stream())` line showing the cause of your exception.

If you don't want to convert all the suspicious method references to lambdas, you may have a clue looking into the previous frame (ReferencePipeline.java:267). This line in JDK source [appears](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java?av=f#270) inside the `flatMap` implementation, so you may conclude that something wrong happens on the `flatMap` step.

So to summarize:

- If you see the exception involving the terminal Stream operation, it may actually occur on any stage of your Stream.
- When per-element processing is performed, it's likely that you will see `tryAdvance` or `forEachRemaining` spliterator method call in the trace. When you don't see it, it's likely that per-element processing is already finished or not started.
- Check the topmost frame first: it may point to the body of your lambda where the exception actually occurs.
- If the topmost frame is somewhat cryptic / has "Unknown Source", it's possible, that you try to bind the method reference to the null pointer. In this case replacing method references with lambdas may help to understand what's going on.
- Don't be afraid looking into the Stream API source. It may also provide a clue.

Comment: Excellent answer, accepted due to the extensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake, and the commenters were correct: the issue was not the `Optional`, but the source lists! [HttpHeaders.get(Object key)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#get-java.lang.Object-) returns `null` if the key is not found. I falsely assumed that somehow `null`-lists were not collected, or that empty lists are returned instead of `null`. If I filter for that (or check priorly if the headers exist), it works as expected.

Thanks for pointing me to it! I wrote a small example demonstrating the issue for anyone interested:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        succeeds();
        fixed();
        fails();
    }

    private static void succeeds() {
        List<String> list1 = Collections.singletonList("identifier=xxx");
        List<String> list2 = Collections.emptyList();
        Optional<String> cookieValue =
                Stream.of(list1, list2)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(s -> s.contains("identifier"))
                        .map(Main::parseCookieValue)
                        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .findFirst();
        System.out.println(cookieValue.orElse("Code works as expected with non-null Lists"));
    }

    private static void fails() {
        List<String> list1 = Collections.singletonList("identifier=xxx");
        List<String> list2 = null;
        Optional<String> cookieValue =
                Stream.of(list1, list2)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(s -> s.contains("identifier"))
                        .map(Main::parseCookieValue)
                        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .findFirst();
        System.out.println(cookieValue.orElse("Exception thrown prior to this call!"));
    }

    private static void fixed() {
        List<String> list1 = Collections.singletonList("identifier=xxx");
        List<String> list2 = null;
        Optional<String> cookieValue =
                Stream.of(list1, list2)
                        .filter(l -> l != null)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .filter(s -> s.contains("identifier"))
                        .map(Main::parseCookieValue)
                        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .findFirst();
        System.out.println(cookieValue.orElse("Code works as expected after null Lists have been filtered"));
    }

    private static Optional<String> parseCookieValue(final String headerString) {
        System.out.println("Parsing method called");
        //return an empty Optional for testing;
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```